Recursion for n-strings made using ${a,b,c}$ in which abc and other 5 perms don't appear
The title should be self explanatory.
Let $B_n$ be the set of all $n$ length words made using the letters $a,b,c$ such that no three consecutive distinct letters appear. That is, we want to avoid $abc$ and it's 5 other permutations as substrings of our $n$ string.
I also have the recursive formula with me (which I wish to derive).
Abusing notation,
$$B_{n+1}=B_{n-1}+2B_n$$
I have tried doing stuff like
$B_{n+1}(a)=B_n(aa)+B_n(ab)+B_n(ac)+B_n(ba)+B_n(bb)+B_n(ca)+B_n(cc)$
And other related formulas but to no avail.
($B_n(a)$ denotes words in $B_n$ ending with the letter $a$ and so on)

I don't understand. You say you want the recursion, but you also say you have the recursion. Is the problem that you don't know how to derive that recursion?

@GerryMyerson precisely. I want to proof.

$$
B_{n+1}=3(B_n(aa)+B_n(bb)+B_n(cc))+2(B_n(ab)+\dotsb+B_n(cb))
$$
$$
=2B_n+(B_n(aa)+B_n(bb)+B_n(cc))=2B_n+B_{n-1}
$$

Not required for this question, but can we also say, $B_n(ac)+B_n(ba)+B_n(cb)=B_{n-1}$?

I think for $n=3$ the left side is $6$ but the right side is $9$.

ah yes thanks !
